# How can I merge two tables like this? - Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have these tables set like this

```lua
local tableone = {["Gold"] = 10, ["Gem"] = 5}
local tabletwo = {["Level"] = 1}
```

This is the code for merging

```lua
local test = {tableone, tabletwo}
print(test)
```

But if I try to merge the tables then the output is like this

```lua
[1] = {
   ["Gold"] = 10, 
   ["Gem"] = 5
},
[2] =  {
   ["Level"] = 1
}
```

And I would like to have the output like this

```lua
[1] = {
   ["Gold"] = 10, 
   ["Gem"] = 5,
   ["Level"] = 1
}
```

Is this possible?
Sorry if I'm not that good at explaining.

Comment: not too clear how this should work if there are more items, can you expand your example to have 2 items in each table. and include the code you have that is producing the first result.

Comment: Okay. I'm going to edit it then.

Comment: @Nifim I edited it

Comment: And the code you used to get the first result?

Comment: `local tableone = {["Gold"] = 10, ["Gem"] = 5}
local tabletwo = {["Level"] = 1}
local test = {tableone, tabletwo}
print(test)
`

Comment: Please edit your code into the question so we can clearly see what you did. That's an important part of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a simple nested loop.

```
local function merge(...)
  local result <const> = {}
  -- For each source table
  for _, t in ipairs{...} do
    -- For each pair in t
    for k, v in pairs(t) do
      result[k] = v
    end
  end
  return result
end

local t <const> = {merge(tableone, tabletwo)}
```

I put the result in a table constructor due to the `[1]` in the question.

Comment: But can I rename the "[1]" somehow?

Comment: Unless it's in a table constructor, `[1]` is not valid Lua anyway. You can always assign the `merge` result directly to a variable.

Comment: The ```merge``` function could also be the metamethod ```__add``` for a table. Then it is possible to use: ```tab1+tab2``` - Another fine place in metatable is ```__index.merge``` and ```merge``` is a method for that table (Like the ```string``` table for the metatamethods in ```__index``` of the datatype string).